# Select and Insert rows that have changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select z.EncID, z.PatName, convert(datetime,z.ArriveDtTm) ArriveDtTm,
z.Status, convert(datetime,z.UpdateTime) UpdateTime
from
OPENQUERY(linked_db, '
select e.encntr_id as EncID, p.name_full_formatted as PatName, 
e.arrive_dt_tm as ArriveDtTm , e.referring_comment as Status,
e.updt_dt_tm as UpdateTime
from
TRACKING_CHECKIN TC,
encounter e,
tracking_item ti,
person p
where
tc.checkin_dt_tm >= sysdate-1
and TC.TRACKING_GROUP_CD= 5328362.00
and ti.tracking_id = tc.tracking_id
and ti.encntr_id = e.encntr_id
and e.disch_dt_tm is null
and e.person_id = p.person_id
and e.loc_nurse_unit_cd =      664926.00
order by e.arrive_dt_tm, e.disch_dt_tm desc'
)z
```

I want to take the results and insert into another table if the rows is different in any way.  What is the best way to accomplish?
The code will be in a job that runs every 5 minutes.

thanks

Comment: Different from what?

Comment: Share some sample table data and expected output to understand your question correctly..

Comment: previously inserted rows.  Assume the table being inserted into is empty.  the query runs and would insert everything it returns.  It would run 5 minutes later and insert any new rows and any rows previously inserted if they changed.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: patient1 gets inserted with a status of waiting.  5 minutes later the query runs again and finds no changes to Patient1, does nothing.  Runs again 5 minutes later and Patient1 status changes to "Waiting for Lab".  Query should insert row with the new status.

Comment: Shouldn't the row be updated if it already exists?

Comment: No because I want to the how long it takes to go from one status to another.

Comment: You really should consider using the "newer" ANSI_92 style joins. They have been around for almost 30 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ And seriously? You are using sql 2000? Have you considered updating your sql version? 2000 has been out of support for more than 5 years. End of life for 2005 was 4 months ago.

Comment: Unfortunately not something I control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL server [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for SQL 2008+, or fall back to manual insert and update for lower versions of SQL as shown in the query.

Note : It is just a quick query. It was not validated against data.

```
SELECT z.encid,
       z.patname,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, z.arrivedttm) ArriveDtTm,
       z.status,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, z.updatetime) UpdateTime 
INTO #temp_table
FROM Openquery (linked_db, 'Link Query') AS z;

/****************** USING MERGE For SQL 2008+ ********************/
MERGE destinationtable A USING #temp_table B ON A.encid= b.encid WHEN matched THEN
UPDATE
SET A.patname = B.patname,
    A.arrivedttm = B.arrivedttm,
    A.status= B.status WHEN NOT matched THEN
INSERT (encid,
        patname,
        arrivedttm,
        status)
VALUES (b.encid,
        b.patname,
        b.arrivedttm,
        b.status) END

SELECT * FROM destinationtable ;

/***************** Without MERGE For SQL 2000 *******************/ 

-- Insert Part

INSERT INTO destinationtable (encid, patname, arrivedttm, status)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2
FROM #temp_table A
LEFT JOIN destinationtable B ON A.encid = B.encid
WHERE B.encid IS NULL 

-- Update Part

UPDATE A
SET A.patname = B.patname,
    A.arrivedttm = B.arrivedttm,
    A.status= B.status
FROM destinationtable A
INNER JOIN #temp_table B ON A.encid = B.encid

SELECT * FROM destinationtable ;

/*****************************************************************/
```

Comment: I am working with SQL Server 2000.  It does not look like Merge is available.

Comment: Have modified the query for SQL 2000